# What does a 'skein of prejudice' mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I came across this sentence:

> What confidence can we have that the result is anything more than a self-consistent skein of prejudice?

What does the phrase 'skein of prejudice' actually mean?

Comment: What meaning does your dictionary give for "skein"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Grammarist:

> [Skein](https://grammarist.com/usage/skein-vs-scan/) most often refers to a coil of yarn, though it may also be used figuratively to mean an element belonging to a more complicated whole.

...a self-consistent element of prejudice.

Answer (score 0):

A close approximation to "skein" (when skein is used figuratively) would be "continuum" in the sense of something being like a long winding thread.